# Pythonic way to import modules in a packaged .py file

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, dependencies, package

I'm preparing a package for [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) submission with a similar (simplified) structure. Trying to balance memory footprint, execution time, and package design/dependencies.

[image]

Is there a Pythonic or some optimal placement (and why) of `from math import exp`?

1. at the top of *main.py*
2. at the top of each sub-module (*shared.py*, *a.py*, *b.py*)
3. at the top of each class
4. at the top of each method that uses `exp()`
5. some other ways to import?

A gentle/constructive criticism of (or inquiries about) the structure is welcome :) References would be great!

Comment: You should put it at the top of every script where `exp` is used in any class/method/function - imports are cached, so there's no performance issue, and having it explicitly imported in every namespace aids readability.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense and is similar to what I thought. Also, if the `exp` import is at UDF level, is it reimported with every function call?

Comment: UDF? After the first `import`, it's just a cached lookup.

Comment: UDF :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-defined_function

Comment: Found it: According to python.org, UDF-level imports are not re-executed with each function call, but imports are still checked (against `sys.modules`, I suppose) : https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Import_Statement_Overhead